# Read text from a string & edit it

Tags: java, android, string

Maybe there is already a similar question, but I didn't find it.
So, how can I "read" a string and edit it? For example:

```
String exampleString = "Monday: Do stuff & things!";
```

Now, I want to "read and edit" the string, so I get this:

```
String exampleString = "Do stuff & things!";
```

Is there a way to edit a string?

Kind regards!

Comment: Not to sound rude, but something this basic is really easy to find on other websites, you should check them out first before coming here. But to answer your question, literally doing what you did right there has edited the String exampleString

Comment: hmm okay. Thanks for your fast response^^

Comment: I don't know what you have searched but after my search this is the link may be will be helpful...http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html

Comment: Ok, let me ask this, is this the only string you will be editing? Or is there a whole bunch of strings, each having monday: ... tuesday: ... wednesday: ... <--- like that? Or is it just this one

Comment: Going over the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API should be your first stop.

Comment: Just one. Monday was only an example. I thought of something like "if (exampleString == Text(monday).isinString()) {}". I'm sure that it will not work like this, but it should give you a better idea of what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Examplestring.split(":")[1]
 You will get you desired o/p
Better go through java string basics

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring()` or `split()` method :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String exampleString = "Monday: Do stuff & things!";
    String editedString=exampleString.substring(exampleString.indexOf(":")+1);
    System.out.println("Edited String :"+editedString);

        //OR 

    String []edited=exampleString.split(":", 2);
    System.out.println("Edited String :"+edited[1]);

 }
}
```